# Is the following behaviour a new 'feature' in TBB 4.0 or a bug?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, error

I have been stress testing a Tor node I built by setting it (temporarily) as my Tor 'EntryNode' in the TBB 'torrc' file. The main test I have run (using the previous version of TBB - 3.6.6) was to listen to a free Internet radio station, radioparadise.com (RP is located in California). I could then monitor what was going on in my Tor node using 'arm'.

HOWEVER things are not working in TBB 4.0 as they did with the previous version of TBB (3.6.6). I can connect to RP and play the main, 192kb/s, audio stream OK. But when I switch to a 192kb/s direct server link (there are many to chose from) the Tor browser fails with a "Tor has stopped working" message in a box that also says "Windows is checking for a solution to the problem...".

I have tried listening with Tor Browser 4.0 on the RP direct server links below but the Tor browser fails in the same way on all of them. They worked fine with Tor Browser 3.6.6:

```
192k MP3 (US): http://stream-tx3.radioparadise.com/mp3-192
192k MP3 (US): http://stream-dc1.radioparadise.com/mp3-192
192k MP3 (Europe): http://stream-uk1.radioparadise.com/mp3-192
```

What could be the problem?

Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this bug using Tor Browser 4.0 on Windows 7 (32-bit).  The stack trace and behavior match an open Tor Browser ticket.  See:

https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/13443#comment:25

Tor Browser engineers are working on a fix; the above link includes a temporary workaround.